# including protobuf3 headers in Qt project on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, protocol-buffers

as the title indicates, I am trying to compile a simple project in Qt that makes use of the addressbook.pb.h/addressbook.pb.cc files that are generated in the google protobuf3 tutorial for C++ users. Here is my .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-11-07T10:33:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = prototest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    ../protobuf/examples/addressbook.pb.cc

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../protobuf/examples/addressbook.pb.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0/include

LIBS += /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0
```

Unfortunately, this throws

```
:-1: error: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0' for architecture x86_64
```

I'm stuck at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been able to compile and run the exact same (addressbook.*) files using Xcode8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: Add the following to the .pro file

```
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0/lib/ -lprotobuf.11

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0/include
```

I should add *how* I arrived at this answer. Right click your project and select "Add Library->External Library", select your platform and enter your specific *library* (not path) that you want to add, and your include path (the options it gives you indicate such). Qt will generate the code and automatically add it to your .pro file.